# Can you filter an Entity Framework DBSet by a value in the many part of a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I am trying to filter a `DbSet` by a value that is in the many part of a one to many relationship. For example, I need to get the entire list of students. Each student can have many classes. I need to filter students based off of if they have a specific class.

In the context file I have;

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Classes)
            .WithOne(x => x.Student)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.StudentId);
```

In the service file, I might filter student by an attribute such as gender which is why I am using an `IQueryable<Student>`:

```
IQueryable<Student> studentQuery = _context.Students;
studentQuery = studentQuery.Where(x => x.Gender == "MALE");
var students = await studentQuery
                         .Include(c => c.Classes.Where(c => c.className == "GYM"))
                         .ToListAsync();
```

What is happening is that when I try to filter the classes, it returns all students but only lists the class gym. What I need is a list of all of the students where one of there classes is GYM.

The eventual output is for a Web API. I hope that I explained this well enough. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want students where *any* of their classes is "GYM":

```
var students = await studentQuery
        .Include(c => c.Classes)
        .Where(s => s.Classes.Any(c => c.className == "GYM")))
        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `Include` is only needed to eagerly load the related `Class` objects. The query will still work if it's removed